# How to do date rounding in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs

I have an array of dates that I want to round to various frequencies - weeks, months, quarters, and years. The equivalent of rounding numbers but for dates.

Here is a sample array:

```
const dates = [
  "1/4/2020",
  "2/5/2021",
  "8/15/2021",
];
```

Rounding by month would yield:

```
[
  "1/31/2020",
  "2/28/2021",
  "8/31/2021",
];
```

Nearest year:

```
[
  "12/31/2020",
  "12/31/2021",
  "12/31/2021",
];
```

And so on. Is there a Javascript library that allows for such rounding? If not, is there a simple function that would cover the above frequencies? I can write a custom function for each use case but that'll likely be inefficient.

Comment: unclear how you get nearest year values.... How does February differ from January??

Comment: I don't believe there is a JS library for this. must be coded. What did you try to do?

Comment: Asking for libraries is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow. I'd remove that question if I were you.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to explain the rounding rules, and what you have tried so far, if you'd like help with that.

Comment: Apologies everyone - I'll do some more work and ask a better question

Comment: thanks to everyone who's helped so far

Comment: It seems to be more of a rounding–up (ceil) operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a typo in your first array of dates and "2/5/2020" was meant to be "2/5/2021" (which would explain your desired results), this code should work:

```
function roundMonth(dateString) {
  var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var date = new Date(year, month + 1, 0); 
    // day 0 yields the last day of the previous month, 
    // so we add 1 to the month value
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var day = date.getDate();
  var date = [month + 1,day,year].join("/");
    // for string output we add 1 to month since Jan is month 0
  return date;
}

function roundYear(dateString) {
  var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var date = [12,31,year].join("/");
  return date;
}
```

Comment: Using `new Date(string)` with some formats is risky and browser-, OS-, and locale-specific. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @HereticMonkey good to know, thanks.

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse(dateString))` will produce an identical result to `new Date(dateString)`, so the call to *Date.parse* is redundant. But you shouldn't be parsing unsupported formats with the built–in parser anyway, per @HereticMonkey's comment.